# How can i print this on the same line without the next line having the number i just put in the beginning?

Tags: java

Ok, I am sorry to ask such a dumb question but I am currently confused on how to make this work, most of this is because I am sure I made really redundant mistakes but here is the code:

```
System.out.print("How many sides does die 1 have? ");
Die1 = Scan.nextInt();
System.out.print(Die1);

System.out.print("How many sides does die 2 have? ");
Die2 = Scan.nextInt();
System.out.print(Die2);
```

And the output goes like this:

```
How many sides does die 1 have? 5
5How many sides does die 2 have? 
6
6
```

But what i want is this:

```
How many sides does die 1 have? 5
How many sides does die 2 have? 6
```

I am really sorry to ask such a dumb question but I really am confused and need help, thank you to anyone who can help me.
and if anyone is curious this is my entire code

https://gyazo.com/0823acf164bed258330da95158c2ae26
https://gyazo.com/072076d1a987342b3c915de6c28d2943

Comment: So, you don't want it outputted again? Remove `System.out.print()`

Comment: read the documentation or a tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are explicitly printing the values. Don't do that; your "output" is showing both the printed string and the typed input.

```
Scanner scan = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("How many sides does die 1 have? ");
int die1 = scan.nextInt();
// System.out.print(die1);

System.out.print("How many sides does die 2 have? ");
int die2 = scan.nextInt();
// System.out.print(die2);
```

Comment: Ah thank you very much, I see why it didn't work like it did, the int die1, die2 were redundant in the beginning, and its more straight forward to go with          int die1.

Comment: Once you learn about arrays, you could also use `int[] dice = new int[2];`, plus a loop

Comment: And I definitely will come back to this then, I am just a month in, into my programming class and It actually pretty hard to get this but I'm trying my best. Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong in your code. It is exactly behaving like it is supposed to be. Just to be more clear, I just added a message to your stdout and changed `print` to `println`.

```
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many sides does die 1 have? ");
    int Die1 = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("You entered: "+Die1);

    System.out.println("How many sides does die 2 have? ");
    int Die2 = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("You entered: "+Die2);
  }
```

Comment: Ah thank you very much, I realized (thanks to you and the other person) that declaring int die1, die2 is redundant in the beginning and int Die1 is the more straight forward way. Thank you so much!